Probability Involving Gaps of Order Statistics
Let $U_1, \ldots, U_n \mathop{\sim}\limits^{iid} U([0, 1])$ be independent random variables distributed according to a $[0, 1]$ uniform distribution. Now, denote by $U_{(1)}, \ldots, U_{(n)}$ the order statistics for the $U_1, \ldots, U_n$ sample.
Now take $1\leq \ell \leq n$ and consider the following random variables:
\begin{equation}
G_1 = j(U_{(\ell+i)}-U_{(\ell)}),
\>\>\>\>\>\>
G_2 = i(U_{(\ell+j)}-U_{(\ell)}),
\>\>\>\>\>\>
G = G_1 - G_2
\end{equation}
where $i,j$ are positive integers. Now, is it possible to derive the cumulative distribution function (CDF) for $G$? It is well known that $U_{(s)}-U_{(r)}$ has a Beta distribution for $r<s$, so that we know the CDFs for $G_1$ and $G_2$. However, these two variables are not independent.
More specifically, I am interested in the probability $p = \mathbb{P}(G \geq 0)$. Is it possible to (non-trivially) lower bound this expression?
